# How can I create a prop.table from a dataset with multiple variables?

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
YEAR    ID_HOUSEHOLD  Size  n_fem n_male   n_Sec_Edu  n_High_Edu  n_emp n_noemp n_stud poverty_t
2017         320        5      2      3       0           0         1      1       3      -1
2017         300        1      1      0       0           0         0      1       1      2
2017         150        6      3      3       4           1         2      1       4      1
2017         170        3      3      1       2           1         2      0       0      0
2017         420        4      2      2       0           4         2      0       2      -1
2017         430        2      1      1       0           2         2      0       2      0
```

From this table, I would like to create a prop table that would tell the proportions of all the variables depending on their type of last variable. I would like to get the proportions by rows, i.e the first row should tell what is the proportion of women in the sample distributed in groups -1, 1, 0, and 2.

For the first row, I would sum up the values of n_female=12 (2+1+3+3+2+1). Then sum the values for each category and divided them by the total:

```
             -1             1            0            2 
       
n_female  (4/12)0.33   (3/12)0.25   (4/12)0.33   (1/12)0.083
n_male      
n_sec_edu   
n_high_edu  
n_emp       
n_noemp     
n_stu
```

Comment: Could you fill in some more data in that table showing what you want?

Comment: I have edited the question but overall I would like to find the proportions of each row by columns. I don´t know how to sum up the values of each column of the first dataset to distribute them by columns depending on the last variable and get the proportion.

Comment: How are you performing the calculation? Can you explain the calculation for 1st row?

Comment: I have edited for the first row. Basically, I would sum up the values of n_female=12 (2+1+3+3+2+1). Then sum the values for each category and divided them by the total. I don´t know how to do this with a larger data set in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sapply` and `tapply` you can do :

```
cols <- 4:10
t(sapply(df[cols], function(x) tapply(x, df$poverty_t, sum)/sum(x)))

#                  -1         0         1          2
#n_fem      0.3333333 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.08333333
#n_male     0.5000000 0.2000000 0.3000000 0.00000000
#n_Sec_Edu  0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.00000000
#n_High_Edu 0.5000000 0.3750000 0.1250000 0.00000000
#n_emp      0.3333333 0.4444444 0.2222222 0.00000000
#n_noemp    0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.33333333
#n_stud     0.4166667 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.08333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidy based approach:

```r
library(tibble)

dat %>%
    select( -YEAR, -ID_HOUSEHOLD, -Size ) %>%
    pivot_longer( !poverty_t ) %>%
    pivot_wider( names_from=poverty_t, values_from=value, values_fn=sum ) %>%
    column_to_rownames("name") %>%
    mutate( rs = rowSums(.) ) %>%
    mutate_at( vars(!rs),  ~ ./rs ) %>%
    select( -rs )
```

The trick is to first `pivot_longer` to get the values neatly arranged in a column, then `pivot_wider` to bring out just the `poverty_t` data as columns, and then rowSum normalize over these.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long and windy dplyr and janitor approach.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

dat <- read.table(textConnection("YEAR    ID_HOUSEHOLD  Size  n_fem n_male   n_Sec_Edu  n_High_Edu  n_emp n_noemp n_stud poverty_t
2017         320        5      2      3       0           0         1      1       3      -1
2017         300        1      1      0       0           0         0      1       1      2
2017         150        6      3      3       4           1         2      1       4      1
2017         170        3      3      1       2           1         2      0       0      0
2017         420        4      2      2       0           4         2      0       2      -1
2017         430        2      1      1       0           2         2      0       2      0
"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)



colnames(dat) <- dat[1,]
dat <- dat[-1,]
d <- dat %>% 
  mutate(poverty_t = as.factor(poverty_t)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("n")),function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) %>% 
  group_by(poverty_t) %>% 
  summarize(n_fem = sum(n_fem),
            n_male = sum(n_male),
            n_Sec_Edu = sum(n_Sec_Edu),
            n_High_Edu = sum(n_High_Edu),
            n_emp = sum(n_emp),
            n_noemp = sum(n_noemp),
            n_stud = sum(n_stud)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() 

colnames(d) <- c("minus_one", "zero", "one", "two")
d <- d[-1,]
d$variable <- row.names(d)

d2 <- d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(minus_one:two),function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) %>% 
  adorn_percentages(,,minus_one:two) %>% 
  adorn_rounding(,,minus_one:two)
```